# "Convert" quadratic constraint to quadratic objective

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, constraints, qclp

I have a large sparse quadratic optimization problem with a single quadratic constraint:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & c'x\\ \text{subject to} & l \leq Ax \leq u\\ &  x'Qx + b'x \leq u_q\end{array}$$

where

- $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)'$.
- $A$ is a  $k \times n$ matrix of linear constraint coefficients.
- $l$ and $u$ are $k \times 1$ vectors of lower and upper bounds, respectively.
- $Q$ is a $n \times n$ positive definite matrix.
- $b$ is a $n \times 1$ vector.
- $u_q$ is a scalar.

The solver I am using can handle quadratic objective function but only linear constraints. I was wondering if there is a way to reformulate the problem as:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \hat c'x + x'\hat Qx\\ \text{subject to} & \hat l \leq \hat Ax \leq \hat u\\\end{array}$$

Comment: If you actually have the inequality constraint with $l_q$, I do not believe so. But if you do not, then it might be possible.

Comment: Since $Q$ is positive definite, try to convert $x'Qx + b'x$ to something like $(x-c)' M (x - c)$. Then make $y := x - c$ and work with $y$.

Comment: This is a non-convex problem because the constraint $ l_q \leq x'Qx + b'x $ is not convex. I think it should be reformulatable as a Mixed-Integer QP (MIQP).

Comment: Apologies, there is no $l_q$ bound actually. Edited the problem setup now.